# How to do audio pause and resume in javascript

Tags: html, jquery

How can I pause the audio and resume back where it pause if on click, please I need a solution to this code.

html:

```
<div class="PlaySong">playPause</div>
```

Js:

```
$(".PlaySong").on("click", function () { 
let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
     let song = new Audio();
       if (audioCtx.state === "running") {
         audioCtx.suspend().then(function () {
          sb.audioCtx.pause();
          $(".jp-play").html(`<i class='ms_play_control'></i>`);
         //  susresBtn.textContent = "Resume context";
         });
       } else {
         audioCtx.resume().then(function () {
          console.log("play")
           song.src = "Whatsapp-Message-Sent-Sound.mp3"; //set the source of 0th song
          song.play();
         });
       }
});
```

Comment: If the play song works then you only need to define audioCtx and song outside of your click handler.

Comment: please can you show me or write it and post here

Comment: Hello, who can  help me with this code above

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the variables outside of the handler

```
let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
let song = new Audio();
$(".PlaySong").on("click", function () { 
   if (audioCtx.state === "running") {
     audioCtx.suspend().then(function () {
      sb.audioCtx.pause();
      $(".jp-play").html(`<i class='ms_play_control'></i>`);
     //  susresBtn.textContent = "Resume context";
     });
   } else {
     audioCtx.resume().then(function () {
      console.log("play")
       song.src = "Whatsapp-Message-Sent-Sound.mp3"; //set the source of 0th song
      song.play();
     });
   }
});
```